# Use of malloc() in embedded C

Tags: c, embedded

In embedded C programming language, is `malloc()` useful in single task embedded system?

I am working since 0.5 years in embedded system. I never used `malloc()` in 8-bit controller programming.

Can anybody suggest me to use `malloc()` in 8-bit controller programming?

Comment: It can be used. But since you are working 5 years in embedded you should know the downsides of it.

Comment: When you have all memory available in single task OS you can just like access all of your memory without allocating and deallocating it. If you want to write at some memory place, just get it and write to it.

Comment: @V.Kravchenko Well, that's not a very good approach.. We are C programmers, not assembly. And the use of dynamic allocation has little to do with being single or multiple tasks.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It has much, while calling `malloc` is just asking OS for some memory. Here you have no one to ask, as you has all your memory. Of course it is sometimes easier to use it to manage your memory, but sometimes it is easier to find own ways of managing it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The only difference between C and assembler in this case, is that the C programmer doesn't need to know the address where the data is allocated. The embedded C programmer does however know how much memory they need.

Comment: @Lundin Let's not forget about different UBs involving access to memories one should not access

Comment: @EugeneSh. What do you mean?

Comment: @V.Kravchenko Well, partially. I see in dynamic allocation much of algorithmic approach. Like dynamic data structures (like trees or linked lists), which is just a very convenient method of solving problems regardless of environment.

Comment: @Lundin As one example if you declare a pointer to some fixed location and then use it as a base for some kind of pointer arithmetic - you are invoking undefined behavior. In assembly it will just work.

Comment: `malloc` comes with a price.   You'll need to worry about testing for fragmentation and garbage collection problems during long terms of execution.  If you can allocate your memory structures at compile time you'll be less chaotic.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Then problem then is the lack of proper data types to wrap in the memory location in. You would need to map an array or struct etc to that memory location.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Regarding dynamic allocation inside ADTs, it is a very common design mistake to mix up allocation with algorithms. If your ADT relies on a certain kind of allocation, it might indicate a poor program design. For example, there is absolutely no reason why a linked list must use dynamic allocation.

Comment: @Lundin Right. This is what I am talking about. You can't just access any memory you want as in the comment I responded.

Comment: @Lundin Yo need *some* allocation for it, right? So either you write your own `malloc`-like functionality or using existing one.

Comment: You have never used `malloc` in 5 years on your 8 bit controller, that suggests you didn't need it and this partially answers your question.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `malloc` is a specialized function designed to handle a `.heap` segment. You won't even have that segment in most embedded systems. Indeed you should use some manner of static allocation instead, or possibly "alloca"-like functions that use the stack.

Comment: @Lundin It doesn't have to be "heap" *per se*. You can have a static array representing your memory pool and a "dumb" `malloc` just running a pointer along it with the same semantics as the "classical" `malloc`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I fail to see any situation where you would ever need that, instead of just allocating exactly the amount of memory needed, with the right variable type. There is nothing good or worth preserving with the `malloc` declaration; it comes with all manner of type problems and pointer aliasing problems.

Comment: @Lundin But how would you allocate the exact memory if you have a variable input? You can allocate the *maximum* memory you believe will do, but not the *exact*.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You can't have variable input. Your specification must state what is required to handle the worst case. Your program must work just as fine during the worst-case scenario as during any other scenario.

Comment: @Lundin *You can't have variable input* - of course you can. A counter of key presses as a simple example. And to get us to the context - it will also record a data structure containing the time of the press. And then to add some more context - a functionality to *delete* an arbitrary record. Your specification will include the*maximum* number of the records. But your data structure is inherently dynamic. You can implement it with a static array by some awkward representation. Or you can abstract it using a pseudo-dynamic allocation as mentioned.

Comment: @EugeneSh. And just how do you plan to allocate "infinite amount of key presses"? There exists no microcontroller with an infinite amount of RAM. This is where your spec must set the upper limit, such as: "the application shall record the 1000 most recent key presses". The data structure would then be a ring buffer of 1000 items which is entirely statically allocated. Anyone who would get the idea to use malloc for that is simply confused.

Comment: @Lundin As I said - you specify the maximum. And yes, even the classical `malloc` might fail with "out-of-memory"

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes and you must allocate enough memory to sate the maximum limit. So why don't you simply do that? Why would malloc be of any help? This is not even about choice of technology, it is about applying common sense. [Just read this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171257/realloc-wasting-lots-of-space-in-my-mcu/171581#171581).

Comment: @Lundin Because you can *abstract* your statically allocated memory with a dynamic-like layer in order to make the programming more convenient. Your ring buffer is just a specialized version of such an abstraction. but it can be made less specialized and more generic if one wants.

Answer (score 11):

In embedded systems the use of dynamic allocation is strongly discouraged. Behavior of the critical systems should be deterministic. Many libraries and OS for embedded firmware avoid using dynamic allocation.

For short explanation why malloc is not good for embedded systems see: [malloc sins](http://www.drdobbs.com/embedded-systems/embedded-memory-allocation/240169150)

Standards for critical systems may prohibit the use of malloc as a bad programming practice.

For example MISRA C1 and MISRA C2 do not allow the use of malloc/calloc. See [MISRA](http://www.misra.org.uk/MISRAHome/WhatisMISRA/tabid/66/Default.aspx) standard.

Q&A: [dynamic memory allocation -
MISRA Bulletin Board](http://www.misra.org.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?t=260)

Comment: Such standards never get to the bottom of why it doesn't make sense in embedded systems though. MISRA-C is nowadays a generic programming standard, possibly used outside the embedded systems branch, so it just says that heap allocation is dangerous because of leaks, segmentation etc. (Also note that there's a new MISRA "C3" out, formal name is MISRA-C:2012).

Answer (score 7):

No it is not useful. The whole purpose of `malloc` is to let multiple processes share all available RAM memory of the system dynamically, when they have need for it. This in turn implies that you have a multi-process system and that the amount of available RAM is vast, but also variable or unknown.

In smaller embedded systems that are either "bare metal" (no OS) or use a RTOS, such memory sharing does not make any sense. Unlike a PC, such an embedded system is completely deterministic and therefore you always know the amount of RAM needed for the worst case. You also know exactly how much RAM there is on the chip.

The need of using `malloc` on such systems typically originates from confused PC programmers who have picked up embedded programming without studying it first.

[Details here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171257/realloc-wasting-lots-of-space-in-my-mcu/171581#171581).

Comment: I think that `malloc` can be useful in single thread applications where the program is creating memory objects of variable size.  Say for instance saving strings.  If you can allocate variable sized blocks out of your free memory pool, you can create more objects than if they are all of a fixed size.  But it does leave you with worries about fragmentation and garbage collection and memory leaks.

Comment: @infixed On an embedded target with limited memory you should always profile it starting your design. Using `malloc` it is only a (waisting resorces and cpu time etc...) feature that make the life easier for the coder, in first instance. Not sure for debuggers and testers. ;)

Comment: @infixed There exists no case where you would have a "memory object of variable size" in a deterministic embedded system. There must always be an upper limit. You must design for the worst case, you must have enough memory to handle to worst case, and that's it. See the post I linked.

Comment: @Lundin  certainly there are plenty of cases in computing where there can be tradeoffs between calculating something and caching it for later use.  Yes you could calculate your data every access.  You could also speed up by calculating once and caching it for use later.  Said items could be variable size.  So if you can always rebuild your data item via calculation, you can still get speedups by caching.  Especially if you manage your cache, for instance dumping your least-recently-used item.  Getting more speed can be a valid feature to strive for.

Comment: @infixed Funny that you mention data caching as an argument _for_ using heap memory. Now if we speak of _real cache_, as in data cache memory, one of the many huge problems with heap memory is the segmentation. Meaning that the CPU can't effectively utilize on-chip data cache if your variables are scattered all over the place. With static allocation, related variables that are used at the same time can be allocated next to each other in RAM at compile-time, leading to far better data cache use with far less cache misses.

Comment: @infixed Summary: if you actually know what you are doing, you will get much more efficient programs than if you blindly call malloc without a clue about what it actually does. The latter is a PC programmer mindset and will only cause sorrow and pain when designing embedded systems. You must have complete and utter control over how much memory your program uses, period. Delivering firmware that may suddenly run out of memory isn't professional engineering, that's just quackery.

Comment: @lundin. You know that hierarchies of storage speed and tradeoffs is not a new concept.  *Nobody* advocated blindly calling `malloc`.  As embedded system grow more capable they are moving into realms that regular systems were operating at not that long ago.   Maybe you want to have your deterministic system that does things like, for example, going out over SPI to fetch the same data from a SD card each time that data is used, instead of caching it in RAM.   I don't.  Yes one has to deal with the worst case.  That does not mean you have to live in it 100% of the time

Comment: It is neither the whole, only or even primary use of malloc.  You cannot be quite that emphatic about its usefulness or otherwise.  Usefulness and advisability are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

malloc in a system like that doesnt make any sense.  When you do your system engineering that includes the allocation of resources.  Being a single task, that one task owns all the resources in the system.  So it is at design time that you determine how much of each you need, including memory.  Long long before runtime you already know what structures get how much memory, so there is no reason to add the risk of that extra code for something you already know the answer to.  If you have been doing this for 5 years then you already know this.  If you have not been doing your system engineering, then you should start seeing your past work starting to fail in the field.

Comment: The number of tasks really doesn't have much to do with the possible utility of dynamic memory allocation - rather, that variability of data and conditions does.  Dynamic memory (re)allocation definitely has its dangers, but just because there is only one task that owns all the memory doesn't change the need to design how it is used - nothing says you have to have an operating system to have a malloc().  Static allocations are indeed safest - but there are ways in which using dynamic memory to respond to variable conditions when possible can be sensible, too.