# How to free memory following a '\0' placed somewhere in a string in C?

Tags: c

I've written a very minimal whitespace trimming function in C that just copies the valid characters into a duplicate and puts a `'\0'` at the end.

```
char *trim(char *line) {
    char *out = strdup(line);

    // copy valid chars to duplicate
    char *op = out;
    char *ip = line;
    while (*ip != '\0') {
        if (!isspace(*ip)) {
            *op = *ip;
            op++;
        }
        ip++;
    }
    // put second '\0' in string, although more memory is dedicated to it
    *op = '\0';

    return out;
}
```

This means that calling this function with something like `{'F', ' ', 'o', ' ', ' ', 'o', '\0'}` should return me the string `{'F', 'o', 'o', '\0', ' ', 'o', '\0'}`.

This seems pretty inefficient. I'd rather return: `{'F', 'o', 'o', '\0'}`.

#### Questions

1. What does it mean to have multiple occurences of `\0` in a string? It started behaving unintiutively when I duplicated the string with `strdup()` and then checked it's length again with `strlen()`.
2. How do I free the memory after the first `\0` such that it is not dedicated to the string anymore?

Comment: It depends on how you allocated the memory in the first place.  *If* you allocated it with `malloc`, you can theoretically all `realloc` to reallocate it smaller, returning the unused memory for possible use elsewhere.  Beware, though, that calling `realloc` in this way (a) might not actually return any memory and (b) might give you a pointer to a new, different, smaller block of memory somewhere else, meaning that your pointer value might have to change, which might be a (possibly big) nuisance.

Comment: If you didn't allocate it with `malloc`, then there's no way to reallocate it.  And in any case, the number of trailing spaces you've trimmed is probably small, so it's probably not a problem to just "waste" the memory.  (That is, desperately trying to recycle it is probably going to be more trouble than it's worth.)

Comment: _What does it mean to have multiple occurrences of `'\0'` in a string?_ Nothing. As far as the C string functions are concerned, (`strlen`, `strcat`, printing with `printf`, etc), only the first one matters. You'll need to elaborate on "It started behaving unintiutively ... ". And as already mentioned, unless you're working on an embedded device with an _extremely_ small footprint (in which case you probably [shouldn't be `malloc`ing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812732/use-of-malloc-in-embedded-c) anyway), saving a few bytes is not practically useful. Memory is cheap and abundant.

Comment: The C style string _convention_ is that of a buffer (array of char) with a '\0' terminator marking the end. Under this convention, a string can't contain multiple '\0's, it is considered ended by the first one, irrespective of how big the buffer is. [strlen() "Returns . . . the number of characters in a character array . . . up to and not including the first null character."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) It has no awareness of the length of the buffer being used.

Comment: @SteveSummit That's exactly the answer I was looking for. I'm new to C programming and not used to these concerns - I wondered whether it's a rookie mistake to waste memory like this or if even the better programmers do it. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: @sueszli On modern platforms the rookie mistake is often to worry too much about memory. Leaking memory is different from having some slack. Indeed almost all modern array types manage a may-be-outsized array with slack capacity (e.g. `std::vector` in C++ and `ArrayList<>` in Java are typically implemented that way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 2. How do I free the memory after the first \0 such that it is not dedicated to the string anymore?

You can do this with:

```
char *NewSpace = realloc(out, strlen(out) + 1);
if (NewSpace)
    out = NewSpace;
```

Testing `NewSpace` is a guard against `realloc` failing, in which case it returns a null pointer and the old memory remains allocated. (`realloc` should not fail when shortening an allocation, but it is good practice to guard against problems.)

This can be done only with dynamically allocated memory. Your code shows the space for `out` was allocated with `strdup`, so that is dynamically allocated memory.

Note that memory allocation routines commonly work in units of 16 bytes or something along those lines, so reallocating 7 bytes to 4 will not have any effect on memory use. Reallocating ten mebibytes to one might release the memory. (This is not guaranteed by the C standard, and some implementations might choose not to.)

> 1. What does it mean to have multiple [occurrences] of \0 in a string?

It is not possible to have multiple occurrences of a null character in a *string*, because a string is defined to be a sequence of characters that ends with the first null character.

You can have an array with multiple null characters in it. An array is a sequence of elements of the same type, and its elements can have any values of that type, including multiple zeros. Arrays are often used to hold strings. When an array, or part of it, is used to hold a string, the string will simply end at the first null character. Remaining elements in the array will not be used by functions operating on it as a string.

In C, an array has a fixed amount of memory. (For a so-called “variable length array,” the length is fixed when the array is created. It may vary in different instances of code execution reaching the array definition, but it does not vary in a particular instance.) In large part, the array is the memory, and that does not change according to the data in it. In contrast, a string is defined by its contents; it ends at its first null character.

Comment: Woah! Based on the comments above I thought I'd need a bunch of pointer arithmetic. This is a _really_ elegant solution + I learned a bunch about the semantics of strings. Thanks Eric!